# Incorrect LC2 amount in transaction code MM03

Tags: sap-erp

In transaction `MM03` I have a situation as shown in the following image:
[image]

My problem is that some of the values in `LC2 amount` are incorrect (the highlighted ones) and some are correct.
I have read [Note 335608](http://sap-consalt.ru/vanilla/discussion/33137/note-335608-trnsln-of-2nd-and-3rd-lcl-crcy-fm-1st-lcltrns-crcy/p1) and in transaction `OB22` I have the following setup (if maybe this info is relevant ):
[image]

I also checked table `TCURR` and it seems fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Well, this task was presented to me as a programming problem. Who should be qualified to solve it then? (because the consultants have no clue)

Comment: You have two options here. Or you go on an epic debugging session, or you pass it back to the functional team and let them double check their config and master data.

Comment: I went on the epic debugging session (+ 4 hours), so I guess I should pass it back.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you have BTEs that might be causing this?

(I was supposed to just comment this question but my reputation still doesn't allow it, so I'm posting this as a possible answer to your issue instead)

Comment: I have checked all BTE's, but did not find anything fishy.

Comment: That's too bad. I've ran out of ideas.. in case you still haven't got it fixed, you can suggest to your functional consultant to raise an SAP message for this.